# Access to the element during ng-class change in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two DIVs filled with some list of items both using ng-repeat. I need to highlight the same item in both DIVs after click on one in the first DIV and move the scrollbar in the second one to show the item on the screen in case it is not visible.

The highlighting works fine but I cannot move scrollbar by only changing attributes. I tried filter named "scroll" for handle class change, but I cannot access the element, where the class change happened, inside. (I cannot do something like "element.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop = element.offsetTop" in the filter.)

It's possible to make ID for each LI element, pass it to the filter and use document.getElementById. It works, but it isn't enough flexible for my project (there should be more DIVs to scroll).

How can i get the HTML element, where change of class is in progress?

Thanks in advance.

code:

```
<div id="figure">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="highlight(item)" ng-class="item.selected">...</div>
</div>
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="item.selected | scroll">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.

Its needed to use directive, link and $watch. And add a "link" for that to each LI element

script:

```
app.directive("dirRowScroll", function()
{
  function link($scope, element, attributes){
    $scope.$watch(attributes.ngClass, function(attr){
      if(attr === "selected") element[0].parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop = element[0].offsetTop;
    });
  }
  return({link:link});
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" dir-row-scroll ng-class="item.selected">...</li>
</ul>
```